# Haskell. It is required to flatten the same elements in the list in the order they follow

Tags: haskell

How to remove identical duplicate items adjacent to the items in the list?

```
flattlst "aaaasssaaabbbssaaa"
--"asabsa"
```

I tried to do it through the "nub" function in the Data.List,

```
 import Data.List
 flattlst = nub
 --flattlst"aaaasssaaabbbssaaa"
"asb" -- !!! It is wrong!!
"asabsa" -- !!The answer should be like this.
```

but that is not what I need. The "Nub" removes all the same elements, but I only need those that go in a row.Help me solve this problem.

Comment: This does not really look like "flattening". Furthermore `nub` means "global" uniqness. What you need is `group` and do some post-processing.

Comment: You may use `head` like `head <$> group "aaaasssaaabbbssaaa"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nub` will only yield an element, if it did not yield an equivalent element first. So `nub` indeed will emit `"asb"`, since the `'a'`s, `'s'`s and `'b'`s after that are already emitted.

What you can use is [**`group :: (Eq a, Foldable f) => f a -> [NonEmpty a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html#v:group). This will yield a non-empty list for each subsequence of equal elements. For example:

```
Prelude Data.List.NonEmpty> group "aaaasssaaabbbssaaa"
['a' :| "aaa",'s' :| "ss",'a' :| "aa",'b' :| "bb",'s' :| "s",'a' :| "aa"]
```

You still need to post-process this, such that for each [**`NonEmpty`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html#t:NonEmpty) element, you return the first element. I leave that as an exercise. *Hint*: you can use pattern matching for that.

Comment: The "flattlst" function should work on any list, not just that.

Comment: @Seliverstov: it does, like the type signature says, it works on any `Foldable` that wraps elements `a` where `Eq a` holds, so on lists of `Char`s, `NonEmpty`s of `Int`s, `Tree`s of `String`s, `Maybe` of `Tree Char`s, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a naive approach that should work fine. It uses [group](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group) from `Data.List`:

```
flattlst = map head . group
```

Most Haskell programmers, including me, generally warn against using `head`, as it will crash the program if used on an empty list. However, `group` is guaranteed to result in a list of non-empty lists*, so this should be OK.

*at least if the input is non-empty. I'm not sure what `group` does when used on an empty list - I suspect one way or another this will blowup, so add a special case for the empty list/string if that's important to avoid.

Comment: Use `map head . Data.List.NonEmpty.group` to avoid the partiality

Comment: Come on, how difficult would it have been to check what `group` does for an empty list‽ The answer is, it gives back an empty list... which is _clearly_ the right thing to do. So, no, this will not blow up, it's only the `head` that makes this solution “unsafe” but actually the entire thing is a perfectly total function.

Comment: Sorry @leftaroundabout, I would have checked in GHCi but was on my phone, and often can't conveniently load up my laptop at the moment. I did check the documentation and couldn't see a clear answer, but now that you point it out, returning the empty list does indeed seem obvious. So obvious I didn't even think of it! :-)